# Is Bran 7 years old or 10 in the first episode, where Ned asks which one of them was a marksman at 10?

Tags: game-of-thrones

On the 1st episode of the 1st season of *Game of Thrones*, Ned is watching Bran practicing archery at Winterfell and Bran completely missed the target. The other boys laugh and Ned Stark asks which one of his sons was a marksman at 10, but Bran is only 7 years old.

**What happened here?**

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say he was just rounding up.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 Rounding up from seven to ten seems a little weird for a parent, especially since there's a huge difference between seven and ten.  Why not just ask "which of you was a marksman at seven?"  That seems like a pretty reasonable approach to asking this question.

Comment: If you weren't a marksman at 10 you certainly weren't going to be one at 7?!

Answer (score 9):

In the show, *Game of Thrones*, **[Bran Stark](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Bran_Stark#cite_note-0) is actually 10 years old in the first season**. The characters were "aged up" so as to better match their actors and the story line.

This makes sense in relation to what Ned is saying.

Bran would be ~17-18 in the events of *The Long Night* (S08E03).

See also:

- [Exactly How Old Are the Characters on *Game of Thrones*?](http://time.com/5575054/game-of-thrones-how-old-is-arya-stark/)
- [How Old Is Bran On 'Game Of Thrones' Season 6? He's Come A Long Way From Winterfell](https://www.bustle.com/articles/157895-how-old-is-bran-on-game-of-thrones-season-6-hes-come-a-long-way-from)

---

In the books, Bran *is* 7 years old, so I can see why you would have this misunderstanding.

Comment: And for good reason, given that Daenerys is raped in the first season. With her book's age, she would have been only 13.

Comment: So rape becomes more acceptable with age? *scnr*